# WCF, wsHttpBinding and ws-addressing: The field <wsa:From> is missing from the soap messages

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, ws-addressing

I implemented a wcf web service by using wsHttpBinding. The SOAP message perfectly includes some of the important ws-addressing fields inlcuing wsa:MessageID, wsa:ReplyTo, wsa:To and wsa:Action.

The problem is that wsa:From filed is missing from the SOAP messages. Is there any way to have wsa:From in the soap messages when I use wsHttpBinding?

Thank you,